# What is the name of the packaging of sterile bandages?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Some adhesive bandages come in small sterile wrappers like the one shown on the top of the image below. What word is used to name this type of packaging, either technically or colloquially? (Of course, if there is a word for that).

For example, how would a native speaker rephrase the following sentences?

> She was holding a [plaster in sterile packaging] in her hand.

> Company X manufactures [the sterile packagings] for BAND-AID.

[image]

Comment: In the image it is called packaging.

Comment: That is a band-aide (US) or sticking plaster (UK) shown with its wrapper.

Comment: @Lambie - band-aides are always helpful e.g. for carrying the tuba and trumpets.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Whoops, band-aids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think most people (in the UK, at least) would say "[She was] holding a [sticking] plaster in her hand", leaving the listener to assume that it was still in its package unless specified otherwise.

I would call the container a *package* or *wrapper.*

Comment: As a Canadian, +1 for wrapper.  To me, "package" would imply the box the bandages were sold in.

Comment: Note that in the US, the inner part would be called a "bandage". I know the term "sticking plaster" only from fiction by UK authors, and I thought it was obsolete even there, but perhaps not.  That term would not be understood by many native US speakers. On the question, I also would favor 'wrapper'. I do not know of any specialized term for the wrapper over a bandage.

Comment: @DavidSiegel it is still current in the UK. Many people also call them elastoplasts although that is actually a trade name and in any event the ones in the image are Band-Aids

Comment: Yes, I thought it was different in the USA, and I agree with Scott about _package_. To me, a bandage is something you can tie!

Comment: In the US, this is generally known as a band-aid, after the brand name, for sticking plaster, UK. The object is also a band-aid and the outside of it is the wrapper, yes. There is no package here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Colloquially it is unlikely that there is any need to mention that the wrapping is sterile, and often you don't need to mention the wrapping at all.

So the first one I'd phrase as:

> She was holding a plaster in its wrapper in her hand.

And I'd omit "in its wrapper" and "in her hand" unless it was specifically relevant.

For the company that makes specifically sterile wrappers:

> Company X manufactures sterile protective wrappers for Band-Aid.

Though I suspect that the wrappers are made simultaneously with the plasters.